# Why isn't my Ruby on Rails model's attribute being set with before_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

I am making a Ruby on Rails app and am having trouble setting some attributes of my model.  The problem is that I have a :before_save method, yet for some reason the encrypted_password and salt aren't getting saved to the database.  Here's the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password

  before_save :encrypt_password

  ...

  private
      def encrypt_password
        logger.debug "Got to encrypt_password 1"
        logger.debug "encrypted_password is #{ @encrypted_password }"

        if @encrypted_password != nil and @encrypted_password != ""
          return # @encrypted_password was already set
        end

        logger.debug "Got to encrypt_password 2"
        @salt = make_salt if new_record?
        logger.debug "New salt = #{ @salt }"
        @encrypted_password = encrypt(@password)
        logger.debug "New encrypted_password = #{ @encrypted_password }"
        @password = "(encrypted)"
        logger.debug "Got to encrypt_password 3"
      end
```

In the log file, I see the following:

```
    Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed May 02 22:55:20 -0500 2012
    Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "authenticity_token"=>"RY9fSMqb2+tdQ0fIjiEz8cfMTWTi012vCWdCvbxACLk=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "user"=>{"username"=>"test6", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test6@gmail.com"}}
      [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
      [1m[35mUser Exists (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test6@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
    Got to encrypt_password 1
    encrypted_password is 
    Got to encrypt_password 2
    New salt = 4f3464029393829aa562e533773f668c8471c51231611f6f214e654275f37184
    New encrypted_password = 0dafcff2fe75bb6f2b53afda79789cfe13bd3f733b817a0e2e30df98af5829bc
    Got to encrypt_password 3
      [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "is_done", "last_seen", "salt", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 03:55:20 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test6@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", nil], ["is_done", false], ["last_seen", nil], ["salt", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 03:55:20 UTC +00:00], ["username", "test6"]]
      [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  commit transaction
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

So it's definitely making the salt and the encrypted password.  Yet the database isn't getting updated?!

```
>> User.find(6)
=> #<User id: 6, username: "test6", email: "test6@gmail.com", encrypted_password: nil, is_done: false, salt: nil, last_seen: nil, created_at: "2012-05-03 03:55:20", updated_at: "2012-05-03 03:55:20">
```

Comment: which version of rails you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `self.encrypted_password`.

ActiveRecord makes getter/setter methods for your attributes, i.e.

```
def encrypted_password
    ...
    # return something from the db
end

def encrypted_password=(x)
    ...
    # set something in the db to x
end
```

And when you write `@encrypted_password`, you're not actually using these methods, so the database doesn't get updated.

You can see this in your log:

`[1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "is_done", "last_seen", "salt", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 03:55:20 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test6@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", nil], ["is_done", false], ["last_seen", nil], ["salt", nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 03 May 2012 03:55:20 UTC +00:00], ["username", "test6"]]`

`salt` and `encrpyed_password` is being set to nil, because you didn't update the attribute, you updated a class member variable.

Comment: That worked.  I don't get something though.  If this function runs before save, shouldn't the save method in ActiveRecord find that the class member variables, and then save them to the database when it saves?

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't save class member variables. It exposes the database table structure for your model in a way that columns sort of look like member variables. Depending on your familiarity with ruby syntax, it might not be obvious that `foo = self.encrypted_password` is actually `foo = self.encrypted_password()`, i.e. its a method call, not a member.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot `self.encrypted_password = @encrypted_password` at the end of `def encrypt_password`.

Comment: Isn't @encrypted_password the same as self.encrypted_password?